# "Background Modes" Capability not available in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cloudkit

I'm currently trying to implement Core Data with CloudKit like the docs say
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit

In the section "Enable Remote Notifications in the Background" the tutorial asks to activate "Remote notifications" by selecting it as a new Capability in "Signing & Capabilities". I'm using Xcode 15.0.1 and when I try to add a new Capability for my Target I cannot find "Background Modes" in the list.

Is there something missing to show this option?

Comment: What what OS are you targeting? You won't see this for macOS…

Comment: For applicable OS targets (e.g. iOS, etc.), you tap on the “+ Capability” button and you’ll see the “Background Modes” option there.

Comment: OK, so this is not available (and needed) for macOS target? This is not clearly mentioned in the Apple docs

Comment: Yeah, it is a different kettle of fish for iOS, where background execution is highly constrained due to the unique issues of battery life (and limited data plans).